# I want to use more then a character instead of char in switch case, i.e. more then a character

Tags: c#

I want to use more then a character instead of char in switch case, time being I found the alternative and  used numbers, but I want to use full more characters instead. Since I have many options in switch case so finding difficult to use char so thought to use more then a character

I tried but it is giving error, Is there any alternative using enum or likewise
I have just pasted an excerpts from my whole code.

```
string question = @"What Operation you need to perform
            1-Addition: 
            2-Subtraction:
            3-Multiplication:
            4-FindLargestElementInMatrix:
            5-FindSmallestElementInMatrix:
            6-DisplayLowerTriangularMatrix:
            7-DisplayUpperTriangularMatrix:
            8-FindTransposeOfMatrix:
            9-CheckIfTwoMatricesEqual:
            10-CheckIfTwoMatrixIsIdentityMatrix:
            11-SumOfDiagonalElementsOfMatrix:
            12-SumOfEachRowOfMatrix:
            13-SumOfEachColumnOfMatrix: 
            14-InterchangeRowsOfMatrix: 
            15-InterchangeColumnsOfMatrix: ";
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (Char.ToUpper(ch))
            {
                case '1':
                int[,] Add = new int[10, 10];
                Matrices mat = new Matrices();
                Add[i, j] = mat.AdditionOfMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, A, B, Add);
                //Add[i, j] = Matrices.AdditionOfMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, A, B, Add);
                Console.Write("\nSum Matrix :\n");
                Matrices.PrintMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, Add);
                break;

                case '2':
                int[,] Sub = new int[10, 10];
                Sub[i, j] = Matrices.SubtractionOfMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, A, B, Sub);
                Console.Write("\nSubtract Matrix :\n");
                Matrices.PrintMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, Sub);
                break;
```

Also can anyone guide me :
Need to check for switch case - if simply pressed enter then exception should be handled, how to do that ?

Comment: `ReadLine` gives you a `string` - so: just `switch` on that? i.e. `case "12": // SumOfEachRowOfMatrix` etc? Just pressing Enter would be `case "": // empty`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is with strings, like @Marc Garvell said in the comment:

```
string question = @"What Operation you need to perform
        1-Addition: 
        2-Subtraction:
        3-Multiplication:
        4-FindLargestElementInMatrix:
        5-FindSmallestElementInMatrix:
        6-DisplayLowerTriangularMatrix:
        7-DisplayUpperTriangularMatrix:
        8-FindTransposeOfMatrix:
        9-CheckIfTwoMatricesEqual:
        10-CheckIfTwoMatrixIsIdentityMatrix:
        11-SumOfDiagonalElementsOfMatrix:
        12-SumOfEachRowOfMatrix:
        13-SumOfEachColumnOfMatrix: 
        14-InterchangeRowsOfMatrix: 
        15-InterchangeColumnsOfMatrix: ";
Console.WriteLine(question);
var selectedQuestion = Console.ReadLine();

switch (selectedQuestion)
{
    case "1":
        // your code
        break;

    case "2":
        // your code
        break;
    default:
         throw new Exception("Error");
}
```

And use default to throw your exception. If no case is matching, your switch will go to default and throws the exception. For example if only Enter is clicked or a alphabetical character.

Additional, you can check the strings before the switch, if it's an integer. Then you could change your switch to integer:

```
string? selectedQuestion = "";
int selectedQuestionInt;
while (!int.TryParse(selectedQuestion, out selectedQuestionInt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    selectedQuestion = Console.ReadLine();
}

switch (selectedQuestionInt)
{
    case 1:
        // your code
        break;

    case 2:
        // your code
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What about using string instead of number or character

Comment: The first code-example uses string instead of char/int